# How to check if any day of given week number falls between range of date intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet (1) where header cells of columns hold week numbers and dates of mondays per every week.
Then i have another sheet (2) of reservations. I would need to create reservation view to sheet 1 where each cell of each resource row checks from sheet 2 if *any day in current week* hits any reservation from sheet 2 and return a number for that cell (for formatting purposes, number 1 in example below). There are multiple rows in sheet 2 for each unique resource, so i could not use VLOOKUP, since it returns only first occurrence.

Those numbers 1,2,3,4... in sheet 1 are ISO week numbers 1-53.

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

I've tried to approach this with IF/AND/VLOOKUP, but with no success...
`=IF(AND(D$7>=VLOOKUP(B9;gantt_data!$A$3:$E$52;4;FALSE);D$7<=VLOOKUP(B9;gantt_data!$A$3:$E$52;5;FALSE);;);1;)`

Thank you for help already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a simple COUNIFS will do the job. Please try this formula. Paste it into your cell B9 of your table on Sheet1 and copy it from there to the right and down as required.

`=COUNTIFS(Table1[Task Name],$A10,Table1[Reservation start],"<=" & B$7,Table1[Reservation end],">" & B$7+7)`

Note that I presumed your Sheet2 to hold Table1. Please replace the range with another name if a range `Table1` doesn't comprise of the DataBodyRange of your table on Sheet2. To avoid seeing all the zeroes please format the cells with the formula as *Custom* `0;;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=IFERROR(1/SUMPRODUCT(($B4=$A$16:$A$24)*((DATEVALUE(C$2 & C$1)+7)>=$C$16:$C$24)*(DATEVALUE(C$2 & C$1)<$D$16:$D$24));"")
```

[image]